# Perlin noise squares don't match

Tags: c, perlin-noise

I'm trying to figure out how does Perlin noise works in two dimensions.

Following the [article from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) and [this tutorial](https://flafla2.github.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html), I made an implementation for C:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

// array has 3 gradient vectors in each row
const float GRAD[] =
{
        -0.8,  0.5,  0.6, -0.3,  0.9, -0.1,
         0.5, -0.9,  0.4,  0.8, -0.5,  0.9,
        -0.1,  0.6, -0.4,  0.5,  0.7, -0.6
};

// dot product of gradient and distance vectors
float dot(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1)
{
        return x0 * x1 + y0 * y1;
}

// linear interpolation
float lerp(float a0, float a1, float t)
{
        return a0 + t * (a1 - a0);
}

int perlin(int x, int y, int amp)
{
        float xf, yf, x0, x1;
        int i;
        div_t xi, yi;

        xi = div(x, amp);
        yi = div(y, amp);

        // local x and y
        xf = (float)xi.rem / (float)amp;
        yf = (float)yi.rem / (float)amp;

        i  = 3 * (2 * yi.quot + xi.quot);

        x0 = lerp
        (
                dot(xf       , yf      , GRAD[i    ], GRAD[i + 1]),
                dot(1.0f - xf, yf      , GRAD[i + 2], GRAD[i + 3]),
        xf);

        i += 6;

        x1 = lerp
        (
                dot(xf       , 1.0f - yf, GRAD[i    ], GRAD[i + 1]),
                dot(1.0f - xf, 1.0f - yf, GRAD[i + 2], GRAD[i + 3]),
        xf);

        // the final value should be in the range [0..255]
        return (int)(255.0f * lerp(x0, x1, yf));
}
```

With `amplitude = 400` the output looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8b1A.png]

I've also tried smoothstep function by using `t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10)` instead of `xf` and `yf` but it didn't help:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sar6.png]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by applying `smoothstep` function to `xf` and `yf` in the whole `perlin` function (instead of using it only inside `lerp`) and replacing `3 * (2 * yi.quot + xi.quot)` to `2 * (3 * yi.quot + xi.quot)`